# "Shave in the open"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "shave in the open" mean? All Quiet On The Western Front

> We stick out our chests, **shave in the open**, shove our hands in our pockets, inspect the recruits and feel ourselves stone-age veterans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to do personal grooming, specifically facial hair removal (shave), in each others' presence (the open) rather than in their private bathrooms.

Comment: Or 'in the open air', since it presumably refers to soldiers on active service.